# AutoMapper Exception in inner entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have Entities and Dtos like below

```
public abstract class ProductEntity : BaseEntity {
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<BrandEntity>? Brands { get; set; }
}

public class ProductReadDto {
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IdTitleReadDto>? Brands { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCreateUpdateDto {
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Guid>? Brands { get; set; }
}


public class BrandEntity : BaseEntity {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductEntity>? Product { get; set; }
}

public class BrandReadDto {
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }
}

public class BrandCreateUpdateDto {
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }
}

public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile {
    public AutoMapperProfile() {
        CreateMap<BrandEntity, IdTitleReadDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<BrandEntity, IdTitleCreateUpdateDto>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<ProductEntity, ProductReadDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<ProductEntity, ProductCreateUpdateDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I get error on creating product when I pass brands

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
ProductCreateUpdateDto -> ProductEntity
Utilities_aspnet.Product.ProductCreateUpdateDto -> Utilities_aspnet.Product.ProductEntity

Type Map configuration:
ProductCreateUpdateDto -> ProductEntity
Utilities_aspnet.Product.ProductCreateUpdateDto -> Utilities_aspnet.Product.ProductEntity

Destination Member:
Reference

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Guid -> ReferenceEntity
System.Guid -> Utilities_aspnet.IdTitle.ReferenceEntity
   at lambda_method1810(Closure , Guid , ReferenceEntity , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method1809(Closure , Object , ProductEntity , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method1809(Closure , Object , ProductEntity , ResolutionContext )
```

Comment: Could it be related to the mapping from:
public IEnumerable<Guid>? Brands { get; set; } (in ProductCreateUpdateDto)
to
public IEnumerable<BrandEntity>? Brands { get; set; } (in ProductEntity)
?
My guess is AutoMapper doesn't know how to map a List of Guid to a List of BrandEntity (and in this case, you have to add the mapping explicitly

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping to `ProjectEntity`; but `ProjectEntity` is not withing these clases you've shared. Maybe you're trying to map to `ProductEntity`

Comment: sorry that was a mistake in asking the question. I have two classes, one in Product, one is Project, I put wrong one... fixing it now